# How to hide overflowed item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container holding 6 images horizontally.

Each image has a minimum width of 120px.

If there is not enough space to fit an entire image, the image is wrapped to the next line and is hidden.

Right now, when there is not enough space to fit an entire image, the image is still shown, partially. You can see the lines as it wraps to the bottom. How can I hide these lines?

I posted my entire code in jsfiddle as my code exceeds the number of characters allowed in a stackoverflow post: https://jsfiddle.net/zbocxu52/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(59%) sepia(11%) saturate(655%) hue-rotate(172deg) brightness(94%) contrast(88%);
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto 0;
}


svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It's not an `overflow` issue. `overflow: hidden` is working fine. It's just that you have too much height on the container. Try `height: 46px`. https://jsfiddle.net/nkp3rzog/

Comment: why repeating the same question? you also got a new answer doing exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

**Overflow: hidden** will hide the content when the content is more then specified height and width. You have added height as 50px so it hiding everything after 50px. If you want to hide the image in 2nd row then you have to reduce the div's height.